# C++11: Implementing a Selector between std::array and std::unordered_map according to item count

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming

I'm trying to create a mapping class that would automatically select the proper implementation according to the possible value range. If the value range is up to 256, use an `std::array`, otherwise, use `std::unordered_map`.

```
template<typename KeyType, typename ValType>
class MapImpl : public std::unordered_map<KeyType,ValType>
{
  void foo() { std::cout << "Map foo" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename ValType, std::size_t Size>
class ArrImpl : public std::array<ValType,Size>
{
public:
  void foo() { std::cout << "Arr foo" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename KeyType, typename ValType,
         KeyType min_value = boost::integer_traits<KeyType>::const_min,
         KeyType max_value = boost::integer_traits<KeyType>::const_max>
class MappingSelector
{
public:
  void bar() { map.foo(); }
private:
  typedef std::conditional<(max_value-min_value < 256),
                           ArrImpl<ValType,max_value-min_value+1>,
                           MapImpl<KeyType,ValType>
                          > MappingType;
  MappingType map;
};
```

So far so good(?)
I then instantiate it with:

```
MappingSelector<unsigned char, double> ms;
ms.bar();
```

However, the compiler doesn't seem to like this and tells me that my `MappingType` has no member named `foo`.

Comment: Have you defined `foo`?

Comment: Yes. `foo` is defined for both Impl classes

Comment: I also can't use `size()`, `at()` or `operator[]` even though both types have them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) doesn't define directly the resulting type, but it defines a struct which has a `typedef type` which is the corresponding type.

This means that you must qualify the specific type, so your typedef should be

```
typedef std::conditional<(max_value-min_value < 256),
ArrImpl<ValType,max_value-min_value+1>,
MapImpl<KeyType,ValType>
> MappingType;
typename MappingType::type map;
    ^ requires typename for unambiguation
                       ^ ::type is the real typedef
```

Or you can typedef `MappingType` directly by qualifying it with `::type`, same result. Actually, since you are working with C++11 you can also use `using`, eg:

```
using MappingType = typename std::conditional<(max_value-min_value < 256),
ArrImpl<ValType,max_value-min_value+1>,
MapImpl<KeyType,ValType>
>::type;

MappingType map;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be with

```
typedef std::conditional<(max_value-min_value < 256),
                       ArrImpl<ValType,max_value-min_value+1>,
                       MapImpl<KeyType,ValType>
                      > MappingType;
```

Where you might have meant

```
typedef typename std::conditional<(max_value-min_value < 256),
                       ArrImpl<ValType,max_value-min_value+1>,
                       MapImpl<KeyType,ValType>
                      >::type MappingType;
```

You didn't actually `typedef` here one of the types you meant (IIUC); rather. you `typedef`ed the "if statement" of the type.

---

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) examples of how to use this construct.

Answer (score 2):

`std::conditional` is a trait class that exposes the chosen type as `::type`. So you need to do this:

```
  typedef typename std::conditional<...>::type MappingType;
```

If you have C++14, you can simplify this by using the alias template instead:

```
  typedef std::conditional_t<...> MappingType;
```